# How to get the following data via a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the following data, how do I write a SQL server query to only get the records marked with an 'X' below? Basically I want the record with the MAX date for each group of records that are similar. There are two groups below; the first only has data in KEY1, the second has data in both KEY1 and KEY2. I tried using the OVER statement but could get what I needed. Thanks.

DATE------KEY1------KEY2

01-Jan......abc..........NULL

02-Jan......def...........NULL 'X'

12-Feb......abc.........123

14-Feb......abc.........456 'X'

**So here is a re-wording of the problem with a more realistic data set.**

```
Row     Date     Rate     Key1     Key2     Key3

1       01-Jan   150      12345  
2       05-Jan   155      12345     
3       01-Jan   160      12345    J100 
4       07-Feb   170      12345    J100 
5       09-Jan   170      12345    K200 
6       14-Jan   150      12345    J100     ABC
7       23-Jan   175      12345    J100     ABC
```

The rows I want to get are 2, 4, 5 and 7 because they each represent the maximum date for each unique combinations of the three key columns. Hope that makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you want a query max(date) and grouped by key 1, right??

Comment: Is one group the three rows with 'abc' in key1 - and the other group the single row with 'def' in key1?

Comment: I shouldn't have used 'abc' for the fourth row's value for KEY1, as it confused the question. The records are grouped by whether they contain values in just KEY1, or both KEY1 and KEY2. So in the example, records 1 and 2 are group1, and records 3 and 4 are group 2.

Comment: I think I messed up this data example, and so made the question erroneous. I will try again shortly with the correct data, and will rephrase my question

Comment: This is one of the questions I always ask on interviews when people come and claim that they know SQL =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct LAST_VALUE(date) over (partition by key1, key2, key3 order by date) date,
                LAST_VALUE(rate) over (partition by key1, key2, key3 order by date) rate,
                LAST_VALUE(key1) over (partition by key1, key2, key3 order by date) key1,
                LAST_VALUE(key2) over (partition by key1, key2, key3 order by date) key2,
                LAST_VALUE(key3) over (partition by key1, key2, key3 order by date) key3
from t1
```

Be mindfull though, that this will work only SQL Server 2012.

On other versions

```
  select t1.* 
    from t1, (select key1, key2, key3, max(date) date from t1 group by key1, key2, key3)) t2
where t2.key1 = t1.key1 and t2.key2 = t1.key2 and t2.key3 = t1.key3 and t2.date = t1.date
```

Comment: I've reworded the problem and added a better data example. Currently the above query doesn't get back the data I need.

Comment: I've changed the queries to reflect your requirements. The trick is to define another field which can be used for grouping. You can do without CTP and group by the case statement, but this will look ugly and monstrous.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try, as it certainly looks more elegant than my hack.

Comment: Unfortunately this query returned only 3 rows in my real data set, the ones with the maximum date for where only key1 is populated, where key1 and key2 are populated, and all 3 keys are populated. I need it to return the max date row for every unique combination of 1, 2 or 3 keys in the table.

Comment: I've fixed the queries. These should do.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but it did work for me.

`select r.rate, t1.* from tRate r 
join
(select max(r.date) date, r.key1, r.key2, r.key3 from tRate r 
join
(select distinct key1+key2+key3 newKey from tRate) t2 on r.key1+r.key2+r.key3 = t2.newKey group by r.key1, r.key2, r.key3) t1
 
on r.date = t1.date and r.key1 = t1.key1 and r.key2 = t1.key2 and r.key3 = t1.key3`